what should I do to avoid scipy.minimize solver from computing infeasible models as much as possible
Python==3.9.5, scipy==1.13.0
My model has some variable coefficients in each round of calculation. for example, for a four-dimensional decision variable x=(x1, x2, x3, x4)，
from scipy.optimize import minimize()



groups = [
  [a1,b1,c1,d1],
  [a2,b2,c2,d2],
  [a3,b3,c3,d3]
]
groups2 = [
  [e1, f1],
  [e2, f2]
]
cost_coefficient = [cost1, cost2, cost3, cost4]

def objFunc(x):
   '''
   here is my objective func, a linear equation
   '''
   value_objFunc = a * x[0] * cost1 + b * x[1] * cost2 + c * x[2] * cost3 + d * x[3] * cost4
   return value_objFunc


# here is the constraints of my model
cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (a + b + c + d) * x[0] + (e + f) * x[1] - 1},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: (a + b + c + d) * x[2] + (e + f) * x[3] - 1},
]


# solve
try_times = 3
for g1 in groups:
  a, b, c, d = g1[0], g1[1], g1[2], g1[3]
  for g2 in groups2:
    e, f = g2[0], g2[1]
    for _ in range(try_times): 
      r1 = random.uniform(0, 1) 
      r2 = random.uniform(0, 1) 
      r3 = random.uniform(0, 1) 
      r4 = random.uniform(0, 1)  
      x0 = np.asarray((r1, r2, r3, r4))  # randomly generated initial solution
    
      res = minimize(objFunc, x0, method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
        if res.success:
          # some code to record the answer


Notice the number of lists in groups can be up to thousands. And I've made sure that the combination of g1 and g2 will not be repeated
What made me dissatisfied was that I found that there would be infeasible in many cases during the calculation of the model, resulting in redundant calculation and wasting time. I want to find a way to avoid computing models of doomed groups as much as possible.
Is there any way to judge the model without solution before computing the model body?

Show us what is contained in value_objFunc.

@Brannon ok I have edited it. By the way, my model has three goals, and my method is to solve each one once, where goal 1 is a linear equation as shown in the case, while the second and third goals are nonlinear; All constraints are linear constraints

Whether a problem is infeasible or not has nothing to do with the objective.

You could solve a linear problem first with an LP solver. If feasible, continue with the NLP solver. In addition, you can run things in parallel.

@Erwin Kalvelagen sir your comment opened the door for me: If I have a single objective optimization model whose objective function is nonlinear but the constraints are all linear, can I solve this model using a solver that is specifically designed for linear model solving (e.g. scipy.optimize.linprog)? Can this model be counted as linear?


Notice the number of lists in groups can be up to thousands

Then you may want to partially or fully combine problems. This will reduce the overhead incurred from calling the solver so many times. The sub-problems will still be numerically independent but that shouldn't harm the solver's operation.

I found that there would be infeasible in many cases during the calculation of the model, resulting in redundant calculation and wasting time. I want to find a way to avoid computing models of doomed groups as much as possible.

Your constraints are linear. That means that you should change your loops so that the last dimension in the parameter space ($f$?) is only permitted to iterate over values known to allow a feasible solution.
$$1 = \left( a + b + c + d \right) x_0 + \left( e + f \right) x_1 $$
$$ \frac {1 - \left( a + b + c + d \right) x_0} {x_1} - e = f $$
while $x$ are at their bounds. But $x$ is unbounded, so... how is it possible for there to ever be an infeasible system? You might have just confused SLSQP by throwing in a garbage estimate. Don't use minimize(); use milp. No estimate will be required, and your constraint matrix will look like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
{a+b+c+d} &{e+f} &0 &0\\
0 &0 &{a+b+c+d} &{e+f} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and your objective vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a \cdot cost_1 &&
b \cdot cost_2 &&
c \cdot cost_3 &&
d \cdot cost_4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
That's the "naive" approach. You might be able to do better by entirely getting rid of the loops, and instead of your outer loops doing a brute-force parameter search, include them as actual decision variables. This is only useful if your outer loop is supposed to pick a single best set of parameters where you wrote some code to record the answer. If you really need every single solution then this doesn't apply.
